# Can access Xampp dashbord on android but not my local website

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

Xampp is running fine on my laptop, but when I wanted to access my local site on my Android phone I can't get it to work.

The devices are connected to the same network.

When I try to access the laptop's ip address from my phone, it shows me the Xampp dashboard, so that works, but when I try to access my site (192.168.43.242/mysite)  Chrome says "localhost refused to connect, ERR-CONNECTION_REFUSED".

An important side note here: The phone browser changes the ip address to "localhost", so when I try to go to 192.168.43.242/mysite, it gives the error at localhost/mysite, which is probably what's causing the error..

Another thing to note is that when I go to 192.168.43.242/mysite/index.php it shows the homepage in a simple layout. When I try to click on one of the links, the error comes back.

I've tried a LOT of suggestions, among others: making changes to httpd.conf, changing ports, opening ports, disabling firewall, editing hosts file, replacing "localhost" with the ip address in the database.

I've spend the whole day trying to fix it, but it only made things worse:) Everything is the way it was right now, so I hope someone knows the answer to my question.

Thanks!